# Wait for process to end and continue code in CMD/BATCH

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wait

I am trying to wait for the process to end, Can't use the "Start /W" because the process opens from another program.

So all in all, I need some kind of scanner to look for if the process in the ***WaitSession*** and then continue the code to the ***KillSession***

```
@echo off
color 02
cd /D C:\Windows\System32
timeout -t 1

***WaitSession***
(Wait for this process to end) MightyQuest.exe

***KillSession***
taskkill /f /im PublicLauncher.exe
taskkill /f /im AwesomiumProcess.exe
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
@echo off
color 02
cd /D C:\Windows\System32
timeout -t 1

SET TempFile="%Temp%\%RANDOM%.txt"

:WaitSession
REM Fetch the current process list. Store in a temp file for easy searching.
TASKLIST > %TempFile%

REM Reset the process "flag" variable.
SET "Process="

REM Check for a process with the target name by searching the task list for the target process name.
REM If output is returned, it will be put into the Process "flag" variable.
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims=-" %%A IN (`FINDSTR /I "MightyQuest.exe" %TempFile%`) DO SET Process=%%A

REM If nothing was returned, it means the process isn't running.
IF "%Process%"=="" GOTO KillSession

ECHO Process is still running.

REM Wait and then try again.
TIMEOUT /T 20
GOTO WaitSession

:KillSession
taskkill /f /im PublicLauncher.exe
taskkill /f /im AwesomiumProcess.exe

REM Cleanup.
DEL %TempFile% > nul
```

The idea here is you keep polling the active task list and when the target process is found, you delay for a few seconds and then try again.

Once it is not found in the task list, you jump to the `KillSession` steps.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But if you don't mind, could you explain what happens in the :WaitSession ?

Comment: @crysal - I updated the answer with some additional comments. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use `wmic` [Windows Management Instrumentation Command](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)

```
@echo off
color 02
rem why? cd /D C:\Windows\System32
timeout -t 1

:wait
TIMEOUT -t 3 /NOBREAK>nul
rem ***WaitSession***
rem (Wait for this process to end) MightyQuest.exe
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in (
    'wmic process where "name='MightyQuest.exe'" get name'
) do if /i not "%%G"=="No Instance(s) Available."  goto :wait

rem ***KillSession***
taskkill /f /im PublicLauncher.exe
taskkill /f /im AwesomiumProcess.exe
```

Comment: I use "cd /D C:\Windows\System32" to get into the folder with the executables that run in CMD. It otherwise just stays in the %HomePath% where there are non of the executables to run CMD

Comment: There is  `path` [system environment variable](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html). It  contains a list of folders. When a command is issued at the CMD prompt, the operating system will first look for an executable file in the current folder; if not found it will scan `%PATH%` to find it. By default,  `C:\Windows\System32` should be there! Try e.g. `where taskkill`. The `where` [command](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html) locates and displays files in a directory tree. By default, the search is done in the current directory and in the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

A vbscript

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessTrace")

Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent
    msgbox objReceivedEvent.ProcessName
Loop
```

Use `Win32_ProcessTraceStop` to only catch terminations.